# Python threading - listen to network while compiling

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, process, multiprocess

In python (2.6.6) what is the best way I can have a thread/process checking a network (message queue) for things while concurrently doing work (compiling). If i receive a command down the message queue, i must be able to kill and spawn compile threads.

Comment: Which OS? For killing stuff it matters

Comment: gnu/linux (debian). The actual killing, building, and messaging, i got. Just the threading/multiproces im having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official Python API for killing threads -- you need to use an OS-specific method.

If you spawn a new process (using `multiprocessing.Process`) then you can kill it with `.terminate()`. Of course, this will cause it to stop immediately -- it won't clean up after itself and it may pollute any shared data structures.

Comment: Its the getting a callback when a process is successful part

Comment: I find the easiest way is to use an [`Executor`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) -- they're in the stdlib in 3.2+ but have been [backported](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) to 2.6+. You register a callback on a future with [`Future.add_done_callback`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback).

Answer (score 0):

As noted, there is no Python API for killing threads. You must either use multiprocessing or  a cooperative design pattern.

If you want to do the latter, you can simply use a cooperative design pattern, where the worker threads periodically check if they should be killed. E.g.:

```
while not self.stopped:
     do_come_compilation_stuff()
```

Then in your main thread, you should set the stopped flag for the worker thread. This is also a useful design patter if you want your program to correctly handle signals such as CTRL-C.